# Receiving a compensation from SNCF after missing ferry due to delayed train

Tags: public-transport, france, delays, sncf

A few days ago I was traveling out of Paris by SNCF Grandes Lignes. The train was announced with 30 minutes delay, but left later than that, and arrived in Le Havre with nearly an hour delay. It appears that according to [Garantie Ponctualité](http://www.voyages-sncf.com/guide/ponctualite) I am entitled to a voucher of 25% of the ticket price. However, the delay (in particular the fact that the delay was far larger than the announced 30 minutes) meant that I missed the ferry I had wanted to reach. Is there an official or generally working goodwill-based way to get some recompensation for the costs I had due to that?

Comment: Was it a through SNCF ticket for train+ferry? Or otherwise, do you have any travel insurance? Typically you need to claim on your travel insurance for delays causing missed connections between different tickets

Comment: It was not SNCF train+ferry. I did not have travel insurance, I had somehow not realised missed connections a use case for it, I may have to investigate such things for the future.

Comment: @Gagravarr In theory, [CIV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIV_(rail_travel)) rules apply even with separately-booked tickets. However they only apply to *ferries* if booked on a through ticket with a train journey. So they don't apply here, but you might try the argument with SNCF anyway.

Answer (score 9):

SNCF terms & conditions, [August 2015 edition](http://medias.sncf.com/sncfcom/pdf/tarif-voyageurs/Tarifs_Voyageurs_aout_2015.pdf):

> Si un train est annulé ou en retard et si le transporteur peut, par
>   expérience, prévoir objectivement que le lieu de **destination défini
>   dans le contrat de transport** sera atteint avec plus de 60 minutes de
>   retard, le voyageur peut, dans les conditions énoncées au point 9.1.3
>   ci-dessous : a. exiger le remboursement du prix du transport
>   correspondant au voyage qui n’a pas été effectué ou à la partie du
>   voyage qui n’a pas été effectuée ...

Google Translate, cleaned up a bit:

> If a train is canceled or delayed, and if the carrier can, from
>   experience, objectively predict the **destination defined in the
>   transport contract** will be met with more than 60 minutes late, the
>   traveler may, within conditions stated in paragraph 9.1.3 below: to.
>   demand reimbursement of the price of transport to journey was not
>   performed or the part of the journey that was not performed.

So *if* you had purchased a combined train & ferry ticket from SNCF, and the train was more than an hour late, SNCF would indeed have been liable for 100% of the ferry ticket price.

However, since the ferry in question was apparently *not* "defined in your contract of transport" (=train ticket), **you're officially out of luck**.  Of course, this doesn't stop you from trying to get a refund, but I can't find any grounds in the T&C for you to justify this.

Comment: Come [join the bounty competition](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/bounty-september-competition) man. ;)